# Falsly prove that $\sin(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I've put a lot of time thinking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834250/continuity-of-sin1-x) question, where one has to prove the discontinuity of

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \sin{\frac{1}{x}}, & x\neq 0 \\
         0, & x= 0\end{array}\right. 
$$

I know the Satz, that if every subsequence would converge towards 0 it would imply that $\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ is continuous, but since one can find the subsequence $x_n=\frac{1}{\frac\pi2+n\pi}$ one can refute, that $f(x)$ is continuous going towards $x=0$.

---

Now comes the part where I can't seem to find my mistake:

If I take the function
$$
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \sin{x}, & x\neq 0 \\
         0, & x= 0\end{array}\right. 
$$

and define my subsequence as $x_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$, couldn't I falsly implicate with that, that $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$?

I really can't find the point, where my thinking is completely off, so I'd appreciate if someone could clear my misunderstanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$ does not converge to $0$ while $x_n = \frac{1}{ \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi}$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $g$ is continuous in $0$ is and only if for each $x_n\to 0$ you have that $g(x_n)\to 0$.

You have chosen  a sequence that not converges to zero because

$\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\to \infty$

Conversely, in the other case

$\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi}\to 0$

Comment: Damn. Thank you for taking a look over it. Really dumb question. Probably just got stuck on it for too long

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$x_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\not \to 0$$

Comment: Ohhh. I completely forget about that condition. This turned into a pretty dumb question really fast. Thank you.

Comment: @MLK Now it is clear! You are welcome, Bye